# How to make a cell return from an index function

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm creating a table which lists keepers names and their average clean sheet odds. I store the odds on another page called odds, and want them to be displayed on the default sheet.

The home sheet looks like this:
[image: Home Sheet]

The odds page looks like this:
[image: Odds Page]

I've tried to use an index function to match the team name on the Sheet1, with the team name on the Odds page, but my function isn't working. The clean sheet odds on the home page should match up to the Average odds of that team on the Odds page.

Below is my function

```
=INDEX(Odds!A:B,MATCH(1,(Sheet1!A14=Odds!B:B),0),1)
```

Which gives an error, any suggestions from anyone?

Comment: How do you know which column should be returned? For Arsenal, how do you know which column is for Čech?

Comment: If you use the "Evaluate Formula" function on the ribbon, you'll be able to see where your formula fails.  That will help you debug the issue.

Comment: @BruceWayne The goalkeeper name cell doesn't have any impact on the formula, or at least it shouldn't its just for me aesthetically. All I need is to search for the team name, match it to the team name in another sheet and display the average odds calculated on the other sheet in the main sheet.

Comment: Which column is the "Clean Sheet Odds", and which the "Implied Probability"?

Comment: Clean sheet Odds is column c, the implied probability is then 1/c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Clean Sheet Odds, starting in cell c2, use `=Index(Odds!$C:$C,Match($A2,Odds!$B:$B,0))`.  For the implied probability, `=Index(1/Odds!$C:$C,Match($A2,Odds!$B:$B,0))` (if I understand correctly).

Edit: if those are off, here's generally how Index/Match will work:

`Index([what range do you want to return, as your result],match([what value do you want to look up],[what range is the value in],[0 or 1]))`.  (`0` will look for exact match, `1` will be fuzzy).

Comment: actually doesn't take the average price

Comment: just a lack of clarity on my part, the clean sheet odds were in row a for the Odds sheet. Just changed it to this =INDEX(Odds!$A:$A,MATCH($A7,Odds!$B:$B,0))